# Why Tensorflow model inference on GPU incurs so many CUDA cuEventRecord API calls?

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, nvidia

I run a Tensorflow object detection model(one of [these models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md)) on one GPU (Tesla P100). To examine the performance bottleneck, I used Nvidia `nvprof` profiling tool to profile my object detection application (performing object detection on a few frames). The profiling result is shown as follows.

```
======== Profiling result:
  2             Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
  3       API calls:   32.13%  15.2177s    434480  35.025us  5.1550us  954.27ms  cudaLaunchKernel
  4                    30.20%  14.3065s    942706  15.175us     361ns  77.372ms  cuEventRecord
  5                    13.39%  6.34349s    117067  54.186us  2.7000us  5.4721ms  cudaFuncGetAttributes
  6                     6.26%  2.96509s    575202  5.1540us     562ns  1.2027ms  cuEventQuery
  7                     6.16%  2.91725s     67072  43.494us  7.2690us  77.337ms  cuMemcpyDtoHAsync
...
```

By looking at the Nvidia visual profiler, I found that the object detection application contains multiple threads. A couple of these threads keep invoking `cuEventRecord` CUDA driver API calls. The profiling result shows the duration of `cuEventRecord` API call is about 30% of the total duration time of cuda runtime+driver activities. I was wondering whether this `cuEventRecord` API call has something to do with the profiler: `nvprof`. If not, whether these `cuEventRecord` invocation would cause performance degradation for tensorflow model inference and what is the point to have these `cuEventRecord` API calls? 
[image: Nvidia Visual profiler showing the <code>cuEventRecord</code> API invocation]

Comment: Aren't these only CPU-side timings? On GPU side, kernel launch could be dominating all timing? What happens if you adjust your CPU frequency to a low value?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik, Yes the statistics I show above is about CPU side API timing (CUDA runtime or driver API duration).  I guess these `cuEventRecord` API should not come from nvprof, as I saw in the nvidia visual profiler that they are invoked from normal cpu threads and interleaved with cudaLaunchKernel API call.

Comment: Maybe tensorflow repeatedly takes measurements to start a new kernel as quick as possible, trading some cpu time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering whether this `cuEventRecord` API call has something to
>   do with the profiler: nvprof

It does not.

> If not, whether these `cuEventRecord` invocation would cause performance degradation for tensorflow model inference.

They are part of the normal operation of Tensorflow.

> what is the point to have these cuEventRecord API calls?

As I understand it, Tensorflow has been designed with a heavily pipelined device code path which relies on extensive use of events, stream synchronization, and stream callback functions to ensure that the GPU(s) are kept occupied and that the different phases of computation are scheduled, uploaded, and downloaded in the correct order.. That is likely what you see here.

Comment: Thanks, if I am understanding your answer correctly, Tensorflow uses these Event Management API(e.g., cuEventRecord) to coordinate concurrent kernel executions and ensure high device utilization. They are not used for tensorflow profiling or nvprof profiling.

Comment: That is my interpretation -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/search?q=cuEventRecord&unscoped_q=cuEventRecord